# Nginx seems to have no idea of "passenger_root" directive despite correct installation steps of passenger

Tags: nginx, passenger

I'm using this guide to install passenger with nginx on a CentOS7: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/el7/

I fail at the end of step 4:

```
sudo service nginx restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart nginx.service
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Further examining of "journalctl -xe" shows this:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "passenger_root" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/passenger.conf:8
```

I tried to wipe nginx and passenger out and reinstalling them, tried to follow the steps from the beginning... I've got no more ideas. Interesting is though that nginx is being installed from epel, not from passenger repo, but it also seems that the latter has no nginx only passenger.

```
yum info nginx
Geladene Plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.rz.uni-frankfurt.de
 * epel: mirror.imt-systems.com
 * extras: ftp.plusline.net
 * updates: ftp.plusline.net
Installierte Pakete
Name       : nginx
Architektur : x86_64
Epoche             :1
Version    : 1.16.1
Ausgabe    : 1.el7
Größe : 1.6 M
Quelle      : installed
Aus Quelle  : epel
```

What's wrong? How can I solve this?

Comment: I've been having the same issue today. I've spent about 3 hours on it so far trying to figure out what the heck is going wrong.

Comment: Did either of you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after my comment a year ago and had to figure it out again today. So guess this answer is as much for myself in the future if I have to install it again!

Following the [Phusion guide](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/el7/#install_packages) to installing NGINX and Passenger didn't seem to load the modules correctly. I believe this may be due to NGINX supporting Dynamic modules in recent versions.

To fix this you need to add the [Passenger dynamic module to NGINX](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install_as_nginx_module.html).

If you already have NGINX installed, I installed `nginx-mod-http-passenger` and this added the correct configuration files for me too.